# Groovy - Unable to load class files from custom jar

Tags: groovy, jar

This as very simple test, and I'm missing something somewhere, which is driving me  crazy.

I'm trying to call a custom jar containing a single groovy class from a groovy script.

the Product class:

```
package test.products

public class Product{

    String name = "Soap";
}
```

The groovy script using the Product class:

```
try{
    test.products.Product product = new test.products.Product();
    println(product.name);
}catch(Exception e){
    println(e);
}
```

the Product.groovy file is in the test\products folder:

```
src
|- test.groovy
|_ test
  |_products
    |_ Product.groovy
```

I compile the Product type to class from src dir:
`\src> groovyc -cp . .\test\products\Product.groovy`

Run my test, and the result is as expected `Soap`, as the class file is located in the test\product sub folder

```
\src> groovy test.groovy
Soap
```

Create a jar including the Product.class:

```
\src> jar -cvf0 test-product-lib-0.2.jar test\products\Product.class
added manifest
adding: test/products/Product.class(in = 2713) (out= 2713)(stored 0%)
```

jar is now in same folder as the test script, and I've removed the test folder so that the scipt can hopefully read the jar:

```
src
|- test.groovy
|_ test-product-lib-0.2.jar
```

Try running the script again, and then get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\wip\groovy\products\src\test.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class test.products.Product
 @ line 3, column 24.
        test.products.Product product = new test.products.Product();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I need to place my jar in the lib\ext folder for groovy to load it.  I was under the impression that it would first read the current directory :(

Once I placed the jar in the ext folder everything functioned as expected.

Comment: A better idea is to put the .jar file on your classpath.  `lib/ext` is for a certain kind of extension but it sounds like you are just trying to add a library to your app.